# UIPageViewController with only 1 UIViewController and infinite loop

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

First at all, I am not using UICollectionView because I need put my *Slider* inside of a ViewContainer and it's not allowed put *repeatable* elements in it.

As my question title says, I want to get work a UIPageViewController with only 1 UIViewController and infinite loop.

This is my current code:

```
class ListPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages: [UIViewController] = []
    let viewModel = ListPageViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.delegate = self

        delegate = self
        dataSource = self

        if let storyboard = storyboard {
            pages = [
                storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listViewController"),
                storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listViewController")
            ]

            setViewControllers([pages.first!], direction: .forward, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return brother(controller: viewController)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return brother(controller: viewController)
    }

    func brother(controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if controller == pages.first { return pages.last }
        return pages.first
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to reference an unique UIViewController because I'm create two instead of one, and I need manipulate that child UIViewController from my UIPageViewController.

Some help?

Comment: Why not always create a new viewController and save a reference to it ?

Comment: let me know if you already found a way to do this, I am interested in fixing this problem